# Running an Outlook search programmatically

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

As shown in the image below, Outlook users can either click the search window (orange) or use the hotkey `Ctrl-E` to start a search in the current folder.

Is there a way to do this search programmatically?  I've tried using the AdvancedSearch method, but it does not produce the same results I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: yes you can do a search programmically.   Maybe better to give it a try and post back where you get stuck and the code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MAPIFolder.Items.Find/FindNext/Restrict.

Comment: Is there an example on the MSDN or online where I can read about how to do this?  I searched Google and only found links to other forums on the same advise, but not how to do it.  Thanks.

Comment: MSDN has all the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx